# Visual Studio 2017 uses own JAVA_HOME Path

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've installed the new Visual Studio 2017 with the Tools for Apache Cordova. 
After the installation I tried to Create a new Cordova App.

In my installation, I've already have installed the Java JDK and I want to use this JDK.

In my environment variables, it is setted up like this:

[image: User Variables]

[image: Environment Variables]

My Visual Studio print out the following:

```
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
Reading build config file: D:\gitroot\HSLUProjekte\MobPro\UebungWebApp\WebApp\WebApp\build.json
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Do you have any solution to change the jdk path, visual studio 2017 uses?

Comment: What are *your* (the user's) environment variables?

Comment: I set the users JAVA_HOME to the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution

After Udpating to version 15.2, there were the following options:

[image]

BUT: Take care. The visual studio installer installs his own ADK and JDK. So you can delete them after overriding the variables. So you are not loosing too much disc-space.